# SD card protected area

Tags: linux, sd-card

The [Wikipedia article on SD cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#DRM_copy-protection) mentions that about 10% of the capacity of an SD card is a so-called protected area, which is used for the security-related features of the card.
Let's say I don't ever want to use any of those security-related features. Would it be possible to format the card in a way so I have access to this 10% extra space on the card? How could I do this in Linux?